# How to filter already filtered datasource in Kendo grid

Tags: javascript, filter, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

In my application, I'm using kendo grid and I'm using `kendoDropDownList` to filter data source as follows,

```
<div class="pull-right">
    <label>Select Value</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="selectGroup">
        <option selected="selected">Group A</option>
        <option>Group B</option>
        <option>All</option>
    </select>   
</div>
```

How I calling the JS

```
$('#selectGroup').kendoDropDownList({
    autoBind: false,
    change: function (e) {
        var grid = $('#allUsersGrid').data('kendoGrid');
        var field = 'Group';
        var operator = 'eq';
        var value = e.sender.value();

        if (value == "Group A" || value == "Group A") {
            value = e.sender.value() == "Group A" ? true : false;
             grid.dataSource.filter({
                field: field,
                operator: operator,
                value: value
            });
        } else {
             grid.dataSource.filter([]);
        }
    }   
});
```

The above code works fine and now I need to search value from above `filtered` result. How can I do it?

I wrote the search function as follows

```
function SearchProductServices() {
    var grid = $("#allUsersGrid").data("kendoGrid");
    var field = 'MemberName';
    var operator = 'contains';
    var value = $("#txtSearchSearch").val();
    grid.dataSource.filter({
        field: field,
        operator: operator,
        value: value
    });
}
```

But the above function searching value from the whole grid. But I need to search value from the filtered grid. How can I do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send an array of objects to keep the current filter and add a new one in your second function.

```
grid.dataSource.filter({
      "filters": [
        {
          "field": field,
          "operator": operator,
          "value": value
        },
        {
          "field": field2,
          "operator": operator2,
          "value": value2
        }
      ],
      "logic": "and"
    })
```

Some documentation: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/data/datasource/configuration/filter

Comment: Thanks for the answer, this is not the complete solution for me,  but somewhat this was helped to me